# How to install Composer Json for stripe Library In Cpanel ,PHP

Tags: php, string, composer-php

I want to integrate the STRIPE PHP Library in C panel
and this ask for some command to execute to install the library 
and in cpanel there is no option to execute command

so how can i install composer so i can use

/vener/autoload.php

file
for integration

Comment: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Set+Up+%28PHP%29+Composer

Comment: To install composer on Cpanel server: 
https://blog.hostonnet.com/installing-composer-on-cpanel-server